# Set-AzStorageBlobContent throws exception: Illegal characters in path

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I am migrating out Azure deployment scripts from AzureRM to Az and it seems that the new module has trouble opening the files.

Any ideas?

I tried replacing backward slashes with forward slashes;
I even called it from the folder where the scripts are, so I don't need to pass it the full file name, and it resolves it to a full name correctly, but it still can't open it.

```
PS C:\dev\pq\service\scripts\azure\NestedTemplates> Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "florin-container" -Context $storageAccount.Context -File ApplicationInsights.json
Set-AzStorageBlobContent : Failed to open file C:\dev\pq\service\scripts\azure\NestedTemplates\ApplicationInsights.json: Illegal characters in path..
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "florin-container" -Context $stor ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzStorageBlobContent], TransferException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TransferException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.SetAzureBlobContentCommand
```

2/13/19 Update:

I created a very simple test case scenario, outside of our bigger script suite and can very easily recreate the problem. I put a file called test.json in c:\, it contains an empty json object, just the curly braces, as you can see in the output below. I am using the AzureRM Alias scenario:

```
PS C:\> type test.json
{}
PS C:\> type C:\test.json
{}
PS C:\> Enable-AzureRmAlias
PS C:\> $sa = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName florin-rg -Name florinsa
PS C:\> Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container florin-container -Context $sa.Context -File test.json -Blob test
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : Failed to open file C:\test.json: Illegal characters in path..
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container florin-container -Context $sa. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzStorageBlobContent], TransferException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TransferException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.SetAzureBlobContentCommand

PS C:\>
```

Comment: Is the path in the JSON file just a disk path?

Comment: Yes. And I tried different ways, relative path, absolute path, it resolves correctly to the full name, but fails to open it. BTW, that same part worked fine with the AzureRM version, so I'm rather confident there is nothing wrong with the path itself.

Comment: Is it possible it's not liking commas or colons in the JSON file? A quick google didn't turn up anything significant. As a test, could you use a different JSON file with just a single line to see if maybe a bracket or colon or comma is making the interpreter bark?

Comment: I'll try, although the error message says "Illegal characters in PATH." I assumed it was my file path...

Comment: Not familiar with Azure commands, but my guess is there is something in the JSON it's not liking. Have run into similar issues with automating JSON configs before, but purely a guess from here

Comment: Tried with an empty json file, tried with a file that contains {} only, same error, can't open file.

Comment: The error seems to complain about the file name, not the content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187883/discussion-between-treblecode-and-florinator).

Answer (score 7):

After reading the discussion from https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8473 (credit to comments above) and following the link to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/09/new-net-path-handling-sneak-peek/ I was able to resolve the problem on my machine.

The second linked document says to "Drop a file called `powershell.exe.config` in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` with the following contents". I happened to already have the file so I added the content to my existing file.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

After restarting PowerShell, I was now able to successfully execute my scripts. The problem started after I updated to the `Az` module and removed the `AzureRm` module. This will hopefully save others time from chasing links.

**UPDATE 0**

It is also possible to modify the registry to solve the problem.

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AppContext"
New-Item -Path $registryPath
New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling" -Value "false"
```

Then restart the PowerShell instance.

Comment: This can only work if you control the environment. It does not fly on a build agent.

Answer (score 1):

If your `AzureRM` command works fine, the easiest way to run the `AzureRM` command with `Az` module is just executed [`Enable-AzureRmAlias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-1.2.0#migrate-existing-scripts-to-az) at first, then run your `AzureRM` command, it will also work.

Also, I test the `Az` command in local, it should work fine.

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "xxxxxxx"
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "111" -File "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\cosmos.json" -Context $context
```

[image]

These are my powershell modules, you could check them.

[image]

Comment: My modules are newer:  
Get-Module -ListAvailable  
Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules  
ModuleType Version Name  
---------- ------- -----  
Script 1.2.1 Az.Accounts  
Script 1.0.1 Az.KeyVault  
Script 1.1.1 Az.Resources  
Script 1.1.0 Az.Sql  
Script 1.0.2 Az.Storage

Comment: @Florinator I see your raise same issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8473. I have replied the issue in GitHub, and need more info. Would you please following it in GitHub?

Comment: I just tried with Enable-AzureRmAlias and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I updated my original question with a simplified test case.

Comment: @Florinator It is weird. Try to reinstall your `Az` module and change the path, C:\ is a little special.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me. The only way to beat it was to use Azure.Storage module instead of Az.Storage, and Set-AzureStorageBlobContent instead of Set-AzStorageBlobContent

So:

1) `Install-Module Azure.Storage -AllowClobber` (without -AllowClobber it fails because of Azure.Profile)

2) `Import-Module Azure.Storage`

3) In the script replace `Set-AzStorageBlobContent` command with `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`

Comment: Are you able to use it alongside other Az modules?