# Script only runs in PS ISE but errors out in PS console

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-ise

I've put together a script which updates Azure File Share with new files. It uses a local folder to transfer the files. This code runs perfectly when I run it from Powershell ISE but I'm unable to run it from regular Powershell console by calling this file `./TestScript.ps1`. Any feedback or suggestions will be greatly help.

Following is the error received when running from Powershell console.

```
Set-AzStorageFileContent : Failed to open file C:\Test\Folder\File1: Illegal characters in path..
At C:\Test\TestScript.ps1:100 char:5
+     Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $fileShare -Source $file -Path $d ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzStorageFileContent], TransferException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TransferException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.SetAzureStorageFileContent

Set-AzStorageFileContent : Failed to open file C:\Test\Folder\File2: Illegal characters in path..
At C:\Test\TestScript.ps1:100 char:5
+     Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $fileShare -Source $file -Path $d ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzStorageFileContent], TransferException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TransferException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.SetAzureStorageFileContent

Set-AzStorageFileContent : Failed to open file C:\Test\Folder\File3: Illegal characters in path..
At C:\Test\TestScript.ps1:100 char:5
+     Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $fileShare -Source $file -Path $d ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzStorageFileContent], TransferException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TransferException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.SetAzureStorageFileContent
```

Following is the function within my script:

```
Function UploadintfFiles ($subscriptionName, $resourceGroupName, $storageAccountName, $directoryName) {  
  $fileShareName = "FileShare"
  Set-Location $Source
  Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName

  # Get the storage account context  
  $ctx = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Context

  # Get the file share   
  $fileShare = Get-AZStorageShare -Context $ctx -Name $fileShareName  

  #Delete old files from the folder
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Deleting old $fileShareName files from file share..."
  Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $directoryName -Context $ctx | Get-AzStorageFile | where { ($_.Name -like "$filePattern1") } | Remove-AzStorageFile
  Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $directoryName -Context $ctx | Get-AzStorageFile | where { ($_.Name -like "$filePattern2") } | Remove-AzStorageFile
  Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $directoryName -Context $ctx | Get-AzStorageFile | where { ($_.Name -like "$filePattern3") } | Remove-AzStorageFile
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "File Deletion Complete.`n"

  # Upload new files to file share
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Uploading new $fileShareName files to file share..."

  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse
  foreach ($file in $files) {

    ## Upload the file  
    Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $fileShare -Source $file -Path $directoryName -Force
  }
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "File Upload Complete.`n"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `-Source $file.FullName` instead of `-Source $file`. $file is a [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) object, not a string. Also check what `$directoryName` holds. Perhaps the cmdlet is complaining about that (too). Also show us how you call the `UploadintfFiles` and how you send the parameters to the script.

Comment: `Set-Location $Source` won't work as `$Source` is undefined at this moment.

Comment: Thanks @Theo @Thomas based on your suggestions, I've updated the code to use ```-Source $file.FullName``` Doing this, I am able to eliminate ```Source $file.FullName```

Following is how the function is being called:
```UploadegrfFiles  -subscriptionName $subscriptionName -resourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -storageAccountName $storageAccountName -directoryName $directoryName```

These variable values are coming from a CSV file and I've verified that they are being passed in correctly. It's surprising that the script still works from ISE.

Comment: I managed to capture the running error from PS console which is now attached to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but I change a little with your code, it can work both on ps console and ISE.

The code in .ps1 file:

```
param(
$resourceGroupName,
$storageAccountName,
$directoryName
)


Function UploadintfFiles ($resourceGroupName, $storageAccountName, $directoryName) {  
  $fileShareName = "aaa"
  $Source="C:\Test\Folder"
  Set-Location $Source

  # Get the storage account context  
  $ctx = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Context

  # Get the file share   
  $fileShare = Get-AZStorageShare -Context $ctx -Name $fileShareName  

  #I didn't use the delete code here, so comment them out
  #Delete old files from the folder
  #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Deleting old $fileShareName files from file share..."
  #Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $directoryName -Context $ctx | Get-AzStorageFile | where { ($_.Name -like "$filePattern1") } | Remove-AzStorageFile
  #Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $directoryName -Context $ctx | Get-AzStorageFile | where { ($_.Name -like "$filePattern2") } | Remove-AzStorageFile
  #Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $directoryName -Context $ctx | Get-AzStorageFile | where { ($_.Name -like "$filePattern3") } | Remove-AzStorageFile
  #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "File Deletion Complete.`n"

  # Upload new files to file share
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Uploading new $fileShareName files to file share..."

  #here, I just list all the files.
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -file

  foreach ($file in $files) {

    ## Upload the file  
    Set-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $fileShareName -Source $file.fullname -Path $directoryName -Force -Context $ctx
  }
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "File Upload Complete.`n"
}  

UploadintfFiles -resourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -storageAccountName $storageAccountName -directoryName $directoryName
```

Please let me know if the code above can solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Ivan Yang for your input. I've made suggested changes to my script but it's still not working on ps console. It continues to work fine from ISE. I think I'm going to continue to run this script from ISE. I'll have couple of my meet mates run it from their machine and see if they get different results.

Comment: @milan21984, can you attach a screenshot of the ps console? and what's the path source folder? it's on windows or linux?

Comment: Script is being executed on Windows machine. I've added the console screenshot to the original post.

Comment: @milan21984, that's really weird. You can try to run it on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

We have experienced the same issue. No matter what changes to the code we did, we were hitting that problem consistently.

The solution we found here - [Set-AzStorageBlobContent throws exception: Illegal characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522744/set-azstorageblobcontent-throws-exception-illegal-characters-in-path)
It was the introduction of the Powershell.exe.config file in the powershell directory with the following:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```